# Read txt file and add a variable to the text - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to simplify some of my code I have decided to move queries and HTML code to txt files. However, an issue has come up: most of my queries and HTML that I normally keep inside the code have variable in the middle. For example, I have this in my code:

```
count = 0
for x in reviewers:
    query = """select *
from mytable
where reviewer = """ + reviewers[count]
    cur.execute(query)
    count = count + 1
    #do more stuff
```

The question is, how do I save queries or HTML code in txt files and then add variables in the middle of the strings?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the solution I came up with I hope it helps
So you can save the Queries in text files in the form

```
SELECT * from %s where id = %d
```

And once you get the query you can place your variable in it. I am assuming that I already got the query from file.

```
query = "SELECT * from %s where id = %d"
completeQuery=query% ('myTable', 21) 
print completeQuery
```

The output will be

```
SELECT * from myTable where id = 21
```

[Reference](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you want, Here's a way to read a file and add a variable name in the text

```
query = ""
f = open("query_file",'r')     
query = f.read()    # read the query file into a string 
f.close()



for x in reviewers:
    query = query+reviewers[count]    # add variable name in the string assuming reviewers[count] gives a string
    cur.execute(query)
    count = count + 1
    #do more stuff
```

**EDIT**

An important point strings in Python are immutable

if you want to modify string then you'd have to create a new string

for e.g

```
query = "Select from Table"
```

you want to make it `Select Col from Table`

here is what you do:-

```
add_me = "Col"

new_string = query[:-10] + add_me + query[6:]
```

now `new_string` string will have `Select Col from Table`

Comment: You're right i was not clear enough, your example makes sense, what i mean is, what happens if the variable is in the middle of the string and not right at the end